# Layered Navigation showing on the left, but products not showing when a category clicked

Tags: magento-1, ce-1.9.0.1, layered-navigation

Help! My layered navigation on the left bar works, showing number of products in each category correctly. The attribute filter also works. But if any category on the left is clicked, there is no product showing in the content area.

I copied some code and put it in Layout Update XML:

```
<reference name="left">
     <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>

<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="home" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
        <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>14</category_id></action>
        <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
        </block>
        <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

The website is [www.amledtek.com](http://amledtek.com/).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are trying to customize your homepage so it will display products from a specific category. You could try this module, which has a few easy to implement widgets for making custom products lists:

<strike>https://github.com/tim-bezhashvyly/CustomListing</strike> Unfortunately doesn't exist anymore

An nice way to fill a category with products based on condition-rules is:

https://github.com/firegento/firegento-dynamiccategory